# How to build a wheel with .py and .pyd at the root

Tags: python, setuptools

When building a Python wheel, the .pyd files contained in the project are not included.

Here's a snapshot of the project directory:

```
my_project
+-- pyproject.toml
+-- MANIFEST.in
+-- src/
    +-- my_module_1.py
    +-- my_module_2.pyd
    +-- my_module_3.pyd
```

MANIFEST.in

```
graft src
global-include *.pyd
```

pyproject.toml

```ini
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=64",
    "wheel",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_project"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name = "Bobo.The.Clown", email = "bobo@thecircus.com" },
]

description = 'exmple project'
requires-python = ">=3.9"

# # attempt 1
# [tool.setuptools]
# package-dir = {"" = "src"}

# # attempt 2
# [tool.setuptools.packages.find]
# where = ["src"]
# namespaces = true

# # attempt 3
# [tool.setuptools.package-data]
# "*" = ["*.pyd"]
```

The shell command I run from `my_project/`:

```bash
python -m build --wheel
```

If this has any incidence I'm working from Windows 10, but I suspect this has little to do with the OS.

When the wheel is installed with `pip`, I want the files contained in the project `src/` to be placed at the destination (site-packages or target):

```
my_module_1.py
my_module_2.pyd
my_module_3.pyd
```

I want to be able to import these modules independently within Python:

```py
import my_module_1
import my_module_2
import my_module_3
```

The `pyproject.toml` example above shows the changes I've made (the commented blocks). I've also tried different combinations of those same sections to no avail.

At best, my wheel contains only `my_module_1.py`, but the `.pyd` file are always ignored.

How can I build a wheel that includes all files contained in the `src/` folder.

Comment: correct.  will have nothing to do with the operating system.